# How to Hide the tab

Tags: android

I want to hide the tab,Only When i click on a particular button.There should be hide all the tabs and also free the spaces covered by them for the time being,because i want to show a list from the very beginning of the top,and it is not possible without hiding the tabs..
Please Help....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launch a brand new activity containing just the content you want.